# Vaadin: How to set validation false to form from listener

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a form and some textfields on it:

```
TextField taxNumber = new TextField();
taxNumber.setPrefixComponent(VaadinIcon.BARCODE.create());
accountApplicationBinder
    .forField(taxNumber)
    .withValidator(new StringLengthValidator(....
```

And I have some validation logic in the Listener:

```
taxNumber.addBlurListener(event -> {
   String localResult = "";

   InfoResult ir = ks.loadInfo(taxNumber.getValue()); 
   if ((ir.errorText == null) && (!ir.name.isEmpty())) { 
      ...
   } else {
      localResult = "";
      taxNumber.setInvalid(true);
      taxNumber.setErrorMessage("Not valid tax - " + accountApplicationBinder.isValid());
   }
   taxNumberStatusLabel.setText(localResult);
});
```

And I want to get a behavior like a ".withValidator... return not valid" in my submit button listener. In other words: I want to have my submit button not working then taxNumber.addBlurListener return not valid result. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that your logic in the blurlistener replicates the validation you have already set when you bound the field with `.withValidator(new StringLengthValidator())`. That Validator is supposed to do exactly that. 
When you click your submit button, all you have to do is validate the binder, and if it's not valid, then don't submit. You can customize the error string that it shows under the taxNumber field by providing a customized string into the `StringLengthValidator`:

```
.withValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Not valid tax", 4, null))
```

I just realized that you probably have custom validation in `ks.loadInfo(taxNumber.getValue())`. If that is the case, then the best way is to replace the StringLengthValidator with a custom Validator that you can write, for example like this

```
.withValidator(taxNr -> {
    InfoResult ir = ks.loadInfo(taxNr);
    return ir.errorText == null && !ir.name.isEmpty();
}, "Not valid tax")
```

Comment: No, it doesnt work for me: validator reacts only for keypress. On amy change. I cant jerk external rest servicy on any keypress to validate unique-tax-number. Because of that ".withValidator" - its not my case.

Comment: try setting the valuechangemode of the taxNumber field to ON_BLUR